# django admin home page - add descriptions to the sites

Tags: django

I was wondering how/if I can add descriptions to the admin home page or more columns?

For example where it says On call and Pdusers underneath (my model is pdUsers).
Is it possible to change that display name of the model? 
Can I also add another column to put a description of the model next to name?

Thanks

[image: admin page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `Meta` class implementation with `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` values set inside of your model class instance

```
    class YourModel(models.Model):
        field = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Just the field")

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "My pretty model"
            verbose_name_plural = "My pretty models"
```

`verbose_name_plural`'s value is visible in Admin panel overwiev page. `verbose_name`'s when you get into the model